# Slick Slider: Get rid of partial/edge images in centerMode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, slider

I'm trying to create a custom slider using the [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) jQuery plugin.

As I wanted to have the middle (active) image bigger than the other ones, I went with the centerMode which does just that. However, by default this mode shows partial images at the left and right edge of the slider.

Does anyone know or have an idea how to get rid of these? Thanks!

[Link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/augard/pen/RPdqew)]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">   <!-- Text Navigation -->   <div class="row hidden-phone" id="slider-thumbs">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="col-lg-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0">One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2">Three</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3">Four</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4">Five</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>   </div>

  <div class="row text-center slick-multislider">
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="0">
      <div>
        <a href="# "><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/350/cats/1 " class="img-responsive ">cat 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
      <div>
        <a href="# "><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/350/cats/2 " class="img-responsive ">cat 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item " data-slide-number="2">
      <div>
        <a href="# "><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/350/cats/3 " class="img-responsive ">cat 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item " data-slide-number="3">
      <div>
        <a href="# "><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/350/cats/4 " class="img-responsive ">cat4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item " data-slide-number="4">
      <div>
        <a href="# "><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/350/cats/5 " class="img-responsive ">cat5</a>
      </div>
    </div>   </div> </div> <div class="row text-center arrows">   <div class="span4" id="carousel-text"></div>

  <div id="slide-content" style="display: none;">
    <div id="slide-content-0">
      <h2>Slider One</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="slide-content-1">
      <h2>Slider Two</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="slide-content-2">
      <h2>Slider Three</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="slide-content-3">
      <h2>Slider Four</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="slide-content-4">
      <h2>Slider Five</h2>
    </div>   </div> </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.slick-multislider').on('init', function(event, slick) {
  $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());
});

$('.slick-multislider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-' + currentSlide).html());
});

$('.slick-multislider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  variableWidth: false,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '100px',
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  appendArrows: '.arrows'
});

//Handles the carousel thumbnails
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function() {
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
  var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length - 1);
  var id = parseInt(id);

  $('.slick-multislider').slick('slickGoTo', id, false);
});
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slick-multislider {}

.slick-slider div {
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slick-slider div.slick-center {
  /*background: red;*/
  z-index: 100;
}

.slick-slider img {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20%, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0, 20%, 0px);
}

.slick-slider .slick-center img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3) translate3d(0, 15%, 20px);
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3) translate3d(0, 15%, 20px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.arrows {
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
.span4, h2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.slick-prev {
  float: left;
}
.slick-next {
  float: right;
}
.slick-arrow {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.slick-arrow:hover {
  background: blue;
}

ul {
  height: 40px;
}

li,
li.active {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The solution is very simple, but poorly documented: set your **centerPadding** to **0**.

In your case, your javascript would look like this:

```js
$('.slick-multislider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  variableWidth: false,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '0',
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  appendArrows: '.arrows'
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKVdPd